# Detecting a particular colour

Tags: effects, dslr, canon, filter, photos

Hey, I have a **canon DSLR 650D**, and I want to know if there are any settings or features in the camera that will only catch/accept the predefined color. For example, I just want to capture red, and everything else should be in black and white.

Please don't suggest Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about photography and should be asked at [http://photo.stackexchange.com](http://photo.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Note for Mods, this question has also been asked on Photography so this can simply be deleted rather than migrated.

Comment: For stills, or video?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about photography and has already been asked at the photography stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

You can't do advanced manipulation like that in camera.  In general, most DSLRs are limited to relatively simple or special stuff like limited HDR processing, simple B/W or basic cropping.  Advanced editing like selective coloration require post production work and often require some matte painting to get it to work the way you want.  It doesn't have to be Photoshop, something like GIMP could also do it, but you can't do it in camera.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not feature you want to.

Comment: So I have to use Adobe Photoshop ?

Comment: I think yes, but Photoshop allows you to create "action" so you can do it very fast for bunch of photos

Comment: Photoshop also allows us to blur the image but camera provides blurring effect so I think there will be a way for doing that

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui That's some nice reasoning there... according to that your camera should be able to do everything that Photoshop does.